# Python - Nash Equilibrium computation - Error in lrs_nash.py

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a 2x2 normal form game using the lrs_nash.py library by executing

```
import lrs_nash
row_matrix = [[-10, -20 ], [-100, -40]]
col_matrix = [[10, 20], [100, 40]]
g = lrs_nash.Normal_Form_Game(row_matrix, col_matrix)
g.solve()
```

which returns

> %run /opt/local/bin/test_NE.py File "", line unknown ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Any ideas on how to sort out this problem ?

Comment: What is this `lrs_nash` library? Is this *all* of your code?

Comment: You will be probably better off writing to the creators of the library.

Comment: It is under this link http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~avis/C/lrs.html. I have installed the library properly and I have run an example. I will contact the creators of this lib for sure. The lrs_nash is here https://github.com/drvinceknight/Gamepy/tree/master/lrs_nash in case you could help me out. Many thanks.